# What is the hydrogen atom wavefunction in cartesian coordinate?

Tags: wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, hydrogen

The ground state wavefunction of the hydrogen atom is given in spherical coordinates in the form of [this](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydwf.html#c3):

$$\Psi(r)= exp(-r)$$

where r is the radius from the center of the atom.

Suppose we would like to work in the familiar cartesian coordinate. The above $\Psi$ means the wavefunction has the shape of a sphere with strength that diminishes exponentially outward from the center.

But what should the *real* and *imaginary* components of the wavefunction be set to initially, for each point on this spherical wavefunction?

EDIT: using initial condition $\Psi = exp(-r)exp(-ir)$

[image]

Comment: see here http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydwf.html for the complete r,theta, phi , which one could convert to (x,y,z)

Comment: @annav thank you. my confusion is there is no mention of i anywhere in the formulas. A real-valued exponential would not lead to complex trigonometric cycles, would it? Is it implicit somewhere that we can deduce the real and imaginary components from the $\Psi$ given on the page?

Comment: The eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonoperator of the bound states   E<0 of the H-atom are real. However if solutions of H-atom for E>0 are searched,  there are complex.

Comment: @James  remember that the real numbers are a subset of the total imaginary writtien as a+ib . to b eonly real it means  b=0,

Comment: @annav i tested the above $\psi = exp(-r)$ having the initial condition of zero imaginary components everywhere. Unfortunately, the structure disperses quickly and does not seem stable over time. The $\Psi = exp(-r)exp(-ir)$ is stable over time though.

Answer (score 2):

The wavefunction you wrote is already real. To convert to Cartesian coordinates, just write $r$ in terms of $x,y,z$:

$$\psi = \exp\left(-\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right).$$

The same principle works for any wavefunction. You don't have to do anything special with them.

Answer (score 2):

Others have already mentioned the conversion to x,y, and z. It's just our old friend Pythagorus.

The imaginary parts are also easy. This is a time independent solution to Schrodinger's equation, and it has real Eigen values.

$$ H \psi = E \psi$$

That got here after some steps from the time dependent form.

$$ H \Psi = - i \frac{\partial}{\partial t}  \Psi $$

We then assume that $\Psi$ can be factored into a time and space part.

$$\Psi(x,t) = \phi(t) \psi(x) $$

The space part is what you have already in your question. The time part is a phase that winds up looking like so.

$$ \phi(t) = e^{i A t} $$

And for your homework you can find $A$ for your original wave function. Hint: You need the full $H$ including the momentum parts.

Comment: thank you. using $\Psi = exp(r) exp(-ir)$ does seem quite stable. The hardest thing seems to keep the atom stable & localized. Most values of exp(-iAr) will disperse the atom. It seem so hard to keep the peaks localized and not disperse away over time. It's a wonder that particles are so stable in the wavefunction.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly enough, the spherical harmonics are actually all polynomials in cartesian coordinates (besides the factors of $1/r$). See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_spherical_harmonics).

Comment: thank you vm. The i dependence does appear for L=1, 2, 3... For the case of  L=0, there is no dependence on i. What does this mean, that the imaginary component of the wavefunction of hydrogen are all 0 everywhere for the ground state L=0?

Comment: Yes the groundstate can be chosen to be real.